# How to i display Directory files on Screen by using listDir() method in ionic

Tags: ionic3, angular5

Am able to add and remove a directory but not displaying the directory files on screen. Can anyone please help me.
Home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
saveData:any;
showFile=[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private file: File,
  private platform :Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {


  }

listAllFiles(){
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.file.listDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "DirectoryFile")
    .then((listfiles) => {
      this.showFile=listfiles;
      console.log("Directory listeing" + this.showFile);
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
  })
})
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Am getting [object Object] on screen.
Home.html

```
<ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let printValues of showFile">
          {{printValues}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me please am facing an issue. Thank You